# Scanf detect leading 0

Tags: c, int, scanf

I would like to know how to detect if input got leading zeroes or not.

```
scanf("%d", &d);
```

This will just change 07 to 7 etc..

In the end i would like to return(1) if input got leading zeroes and return(0) if the input is ok.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know if a number have leading zeros you have to read it as a string, and make the verification yourself. The string `07` is just presentational, when stored as an integer it's stored as just `7`.

To verify that the string you've read is an integer with leading zeros, you can first use [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) to check that it is indeed a valid integer. Then just check if the first character in the string is a `'0'`.

Answer (score 0):

A tricky way:

```
int d;
char s1[1000], s2[1000]; //maybe lower
scanf("%s", s1);
d = strtol(s1, NULL, 10);
sprintf(s2, "%d", d);
if (strcmp(s1, s2) == 0) return 0; else return 1;
```

Comment: A strange input without a leading '0' like "-0" would return 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist, you can read it with `"0%d"` first, if this fails (`scanf()` returning fewer argument than expected), read again with `%d`.

But I don't see why you'd prefer this to reading the whole string in and test....
(So no need to downvote this one it's a useless & hacky way only)

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(){
            int x ,r ;
            r=scanf("0%d",&x);
            printf("%d ret=%d\n",x,r);
            r=scanf("%d",&x);
            printf("%d ret=%d\n",x,r);
            return 0;
    }
```

Compile it and run it with `echo "74" | ./a.out` and `echo "074" | ./a.out` respectively.

Comment: Innovative, but gets fooled by inputs like `"0 123"`, taking in 2 `int`s.