# Printing out asterisks depending on each digit of a number

Tags: c, io

My program is supposed to print out asterisks depending on the digit of the number. This is what's supposed to happen:

> 1. Input: 24 || Output:  2 ** 4 ****
> 2. Input: 24000 || Output:  2 ** 4 **** 0 0 0

This is my code:

```
void histogram (){
int nNum, nCount, nMult, nTemp=-1, n;
printf("Please input a value: "); 
scanf("%d", &nNum);
n=nNum;
do{
    nCount = 0;
    nMult = 1;
    while(n>0){
        n /= 10;
        nCount++;
    } 
    while(nCount>1){
        nMult *= 10;
        nCount--;
    }   
    nTemp = nNum / nMult;
    printf("%d ", nTemp);
    do{
        printf("*");nTemp--;
    }while(nTemp>0);    
    printf("\n");
    nNum%=nMult;
    n = nNum;
}while(n>0);}
```

My code doesn't print out the trailing zeros and I'm hoping you guys can help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: With scanf you cannot detect the trailing zeros (this is just not possible). Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019364/scanf-detect-leading-0

Comment: Changed to receive input with letters.

Comment: scanf is perfectly fine for reading in trailing zeros. You cannot read leading zeros.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with a debugger to see what is doing instead of printing out the the trailing zeros?

Comment: Basically this is the same [How to print `1234567890` to `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0` with `C`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40677052/how-to-print-1234567890-to-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-0-with-c)

Comment: After the while loop, you should just check nmult value. If 10, print one zero. If 100, print two zeros, etc... with a loop dividing by 10 on each iteration, obviously !

Answer (score 1):

It is better to make such a function recursive. It allows to keep trailing zeroes.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

void histogram( unsigned int n )
{
    const unsigned int Base = 10;
    const char c = '*';

    unsigned int digit = n % Base;

    if ( n /= Base ) histogram( n );

    printf( "%u ", digit );
    for ( ; digit != 0; --digit ) printf( "%c ", c );
}

int main(void) 
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        unsigned int n;     

        printf( "Please input a non-negative value (0 - exit): " );

        if ( scanf( "%u", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) break;

        printf( "\n" );

        histogram( n );

        printf( "\n" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look the following way

```
Please input a non-negative value (0 - exit): 123456789

1 * 2 * * 3 * * * 4 * * * * 5 * * * * * 6 * * * * * * 7 * * * * * * * 8 * * * * * * * * 9 * * * * * * * * * 
Please input a non-negative value (0 - exit): 24000

2 * * 4 * * * * 0 0 0 
Please input a non-negative value (0 - exit): 0
```

As for your approach then you have to count trailing zeroes when you are reversing the number.

Answer (score 0):

After the while loop, you should just check nmult value, whose value is a power of 10. If 10, print one zero. If 100, print two zeros, etc... with a loop dividing by 10 on each iteration, like this one:

```
while(nmult>1){
    nmult /= 10;
    printf(" 0 ");
}
```